# Why is the $this->getOrders method always returns a null object in this code Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I am new to magento.I am trying to create a view for the purchase history for users.Already there is a page to display this(As I am using a template).But as a experiment I tried to create a new page with the same content.As my first step. I created a new php block and then I copied same the content from the old purchase history file to the new one**(Without any change)**.Then I called that block in a cms page.But when I called the url of the new page,It gives this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on null in
>   /home/bvbellpm/public_html/newtrades/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/purchasehistory.phtml
>   on line

This is the code which I used to display the history

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $_orders = $this->getOrders(); ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Orders') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($_orders->getSize()>0): ?>
<table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Order #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Ship To') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Status') ?></span></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
            <td><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->htmlEscape($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
            <td><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
            <td class="a-center">
                <span class="nobr"><a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                    <?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                    <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But this same code works fine in the  old purchase history file.Why is this not working in the new page? .I think **$this->getOrders()** is returning a null object.But it is working fine in the old page.As far as I know **$this->getOrders()** is a magic method in Magento.So I think it can be used any  where.Can someone explain me the reason for this odd behavior?

Comment: Earlier I have used {{block type="core/template" template="customer/form/purchasehistory.phtml"}} in the cms page.But when I change it to {{block type="sales/history" template="customer/form/purchasehistory.phtml"}} it does not give any error .But it seem to be empty. So I thinks it is about the type atribute.I have serached it,but still can`t find the correct type attribute to use.Is there a technique to find it.Thank you.Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the new page in your template.xml with the same blocks (I mean the logic not the template). You most probably this template linked to a block of type `sales/order_history`.

You can look at `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml` for an example.

The idea is to have the function getOrders in the logic of the template. If you call a normal block (eg core/template) to be able to call it. Else, the getOrders tries to retrieve the variable orders of the block.

Comment: I didn`t get the idea.Can you explain little further?.I am really new to this.thank u

Comment: In Magento, you have the visible part of the block that is called a template and the logic of the block that is called block. If this second part does not have a function called getOrders, therefore, you cannot use it in your template. You can check MVC pattern for Magento to see better.

Comment: I have searched for the file called template.xml ,but there isn`t a file with in the project by that name

Comment: I think that before being able to do that, you need to study more closely the link between modules and view in Magento. You must not search for template.xml but local.xml or [MYTHEME].xml as it depends how it can be named in your project.

Comment: Thanks.I will try it.

Comment: Christophe Ferreboeuf ,Earlier I have used {{block type="core/template"  template="customer/form/purchasehistory.phtml"}} in the cms page.But when I change it to {{block type="sales/history"  template="customer/form/purchasehistory.phtml"}}  it does not give any error .But it seem to  be empty. So i thinks it is about the type atribute.I have serached it,but still can`t find the correct type attribute to use.Is there a technique to find it.Thank you.Any help is highly appreciated .

Comment: A IF statement is not closed, that can be an hint else try to check the return of the $this->getOrders() but be careful as it can be heavy to display with a var_dump. Zend_debug or personal function is more fit for magento variables and collections.